# Response not showing up in postman but visible when printed in the console

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a python list like this

```
        processing_subfolder_response = []
```

This list is a list of dictionary and I did a json.loads to load the data in this list

This all exist in a function and at the end of the function I am returning the data like this

```
         result['body'] = json.dumps(processing_subfolder_response, default=str)
         return result
```

When I print result I can see all the data I need. Good data but the data never gets returned to postman.
All I see in postman is "interval server error"

Am I doing something wrong? I need these data to display in postman.

Comment: The result you're seeing in Postman suggests that the function exection failed with an internal error. Could you paste logs from CloudWatch for that execution? It will probably have some hints about the potential error(s)

Comment: There was no error. I looked at the logs. It did not show any failure and the data I needed was generated but it just couldn't return it to postman.